# Relacionando 3 tabelas laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-eloquent, relacionamento

[image]

Olá. Tenho um modelo reduzido que está em anexo aqui. Minha tarefa é a partir de users, conseguir os registros de orders que tenha algum registro na payment com o id dessa order e o id desse usuário. Basicamente, uma order pode ter varios pagamentos, que tem a order_id e o user_id. e quero acessar no meu controller $user->orders. Já tentei o relacionamento hasManyThrough, não consegui resultados. Teria a necessidade de criar uma tabela pivot para suprir meu problema?

Comment: porque no `payments` você não colocou `voucher_id`? isso é o nome da convenção, claro que outro nome funciona é que sae do padrão. Cade as suas relações e suas classes?

Comment: Coloca as models

Answer (score 0):

Supondo que você entende como relacionar os models no Laravel corretamente, você deve usar Has Many Thogheter.

Assim:

```php
class User
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(Order::class, Payment::class);
    }
}
```

Você pode encontrar mais detalhes [na documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) dos métodos de relacionamento.

### Caso não consiga com o método acima...

Você pode utilizar `whereHas`

```php
$orders = Order::whereHas('payments', function ($query) use($user) {
     return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
});
```

Comment: então fiz exatamente com o hasManyThrough, mas não sei porque dá erro nas constrains. vou tentar com a query.Eu posso colocar ela no meu model?

class User
{
    public function orders()
    {
        return Order::whereHas('payments', function ($query) use($user) {
     return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
});
    }
}

Comment: Você pode definir os valores dos campos nos outros parâmetros de through... Digo, se a coluna não tiver na convenção interna do Laravel.